# How to send messages back from ServiceActivator to Queue in Spring integration

Tags: spring-integration, message-queue, spring-jms

Hi i have a requirement to launch the spring batch job when there is a message in to the queue and once processing done i need to return some message back to Queue . I am using Spring integration and in Service activator i am able to receive the message from input channel and i am using JmsTemplate to send back response to queue once processing is done. Is this the right way to do it in Spring integration

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JobLaunchingGateway` from `spring-batch-integration`...

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "...", outputChannel = "...")
public JobLaunchingGateway gateway() {
    return new JobLaunchingGateway(...);
}
```

The `JobExcecution` will be sent to the output channel.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#springBatchIntegration).